# sys/ioctl.h issues in linux

Tags: c++, linux, macos, sockets, ioctl

So I have a **known working** version of this code on Windows and MacOSX:

```
int CSocket::setsync(int mode)
{
    if(sockid < 0)return -1;
    u_long i = mode;
    return ioctlsocket(sockid, FIONBIO, &i);
}
```

I just want to know if the following Linux version is functionally equivalent:

```
int CSocket::setsync(int mode)
{
    if(sockid < 0)return -1;
    u_long i = mode;
    return ioctl(sockid, FIONBIO, &i);
}
```

Just an FYI, i #included sys/ioctl.h

Comment: What? No, i used the line #include <sys/ioctl.h>

Comment: Check out [UNIX nonblocking I/O: O_NONBLOCK vs. FIONBIO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1150635/1380680) for a better alternative on Linux using `fcntl`. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3255899/1380680) is also interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i answered my own question. As far as I can tell, they are. At least, the code seems to function. If you want to see the code in action, clone the code at https://github.com/nterry/39DLL-4-Linux